# drupal db_query not working when trying to insert negative number

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, replace

so I have this code:

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO {tbl} SET a_id = %d, p_id = %d, comment = '%s'";

db_query($query,1321,-1,"lolo");
```

but then when I execute it, instead of inserting -1, it inserted 0 instead....

using INSERT does the same thing...

how can I set this to -1?

using drupal 6
also the p_id column is just an integer in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check that p_id is not flagged as unsigned integer